# Groups of order $2520$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a group of order $2520 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$. The property that I want to check is this:

> Must $G$ contain an abelian subgroup of order at least $12$?

If $G$ is soluble then, yes. A Hall $\{5,7\}$-subgroup of $G$ (which exists by Hall's theorem) is necessarily abelian. On the other hand, if $G$ is simple, then $G \cong A_7$, since $A_7$ is the only simple group of that order (in fact, it is the only *perfect* group of that order). Also, $A_7$ has an abelian subgroup of order $12$.

Some further observations:

- If $G$ is a candidate counterexample to the (implicit) assertion, then for $p \in \{3,7\}$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ must be self-centralising. Using the $N/C$ theorem and the standard $n_p \equiv 1\,(\operatorname{mod} p)$, we arrive at the only possibilities $n_7 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ and $n_3 = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$.
- For $p=5$ we cannot argue that a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$ must be self-centralising, because the possibility that its centraliser has order $2 \cdot 5$ cannot be excluded. At least not immediately. In any case though, $|C_G(P):P| \in \{1,2\}$ and $n_5 = 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$. Here $P$ is a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$.
- Since $G$ cannot be soluble, it must have a composition factor isomorphic to one of $\{A_5, \operatorname{PSL}_3(2), \operatorname{PSL}_2(8), A_6\}$. (We have already argued the case $G \cong A_7$.) That composition factor, however, cannot be direct.

Thoughts?

---

[MatheinBoulomenos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/348926/matheinboulomenos) notices that I had missed one possibility for a non-abelian composition factor of $G$, namely $\operatorname{PSL}_2(8)$. I have now included this in the list.

Comment: I am interested in why this question arises for you - in what context. Mainly because, of the Group Theory questions I have seen here, many are about things which are relatively trivial or well-known, and others fit naturally into  a wider context. Here the order is an interesting number and I was wondering whether you had a more general context in mind.

Comment: @MarkBennet    Yes, there is a wider context to my question. A special case of a more general problem I am thinking about asks for an upper bound for $|G|$ when $G$ is finite and has the following property: $11 \mid |G|$ and no abelian subgroup of $G$ has order $> 11$. I can prove that with these assumptions $|G|$ must divide $2^5 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11$. The Mathieu group $M_{11}$ has the desired property and is of order $7920$. What I want to know is if there are other groups with the desired property which have order $> 7920$.

Comment: I can eliminate all possibilities except $\{11880, 15840, 27720, 36960, 55440, 332640\}$. Groups of order $27720$ must have a normal subgroup of index $11$ (and size $2520$), so the answer to my question eliminates this candidate. Groups of order $332640$ must also have a normal subgroup of index $11$, but I will need to think about that case separately. (In the end, I will still need to deal with the four remaining cases.)

Comment: Well, in the case of $332640$ if you have a normal subgroup of index $11$, then that together with an element of order $7$ will generate a cyclic group of order $77$. You can probably play a similar trick with many of the other orders, if you can get some normal subgroup...

Comment: Hmm? It's index, not size.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Still, I think my approach would be to assume that the group is not soluble, then find restrictions on the size of the soluble radical. Often, the soluble radical itself will have an appropriate subgroup. Otherwise, find some characteristic subgroup of the soluble group such that, together with some element outside, you get a subgroup of an abelian-forcing order.

Comment: Yes, I agree. (If some case cannot be eliminated, then maybe there _is_ a group of that order with the property I want.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach. In all cases, we have a unique nonabelian composition factor $T$. Let $R$ be the soluble radical of $G$. Then $G/R$ has trivial soluble radical, and a unique nonabelian composition factor $T$, so it must be almost simple with socle $T$.

If $T=PSL(2,7)$, then $G/R=PSL(2,7)$. (It cannot be $PGL(2,7)$ by order considerations.) That means that $|R|=15$ and so $R$ is cyclic.

If  $T=A_5$, then $R$ has order $21$ or $42$ (depending whether $G/R$ is $A_5$ or $S_5$). In any case, $R$ has a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup $P$. $P$ is characteristic in $R$, so normal in $G$. Now, a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$ together with $P$ generate a (cyclic) group of order $35$.

If  $T=A_6$, then $R=C_7$ and, as in the last case, we get a (cyclic) group of order $35$.

Finally, if  $T=PSL(2,8)$, then $R=C_5$  and again we get a (cyclic) group of order $35$.

(Note: In the above, I'm assuming knowledge of the size of outer automorphism groups of the relevant simple groups, but I don't need to know about Schur multipliers, or Schur-Zassenhaus.)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot shorter! Do you have a reference for the relevant properties of the soluble radical and almost simple groups?

Comment: The fact that $G/R$ has soluble radical is an easy exercise. The socle of a group with trivial soluble radical is a direct product of nonabelian simple groups. Since we have just one nonabelian composition factor, the socle of $G/R$  is a simple group, and it is well known that this implies that $G/R$ is almost simple. (More generally, in a group with trivial soluble radical, the group acts faithfully by conjugation on the socle.) I think all of this can be found in most books, say Dixon and Mortimer (in the section "Socle").

Comment: @MatheinBoulomenos     The implicit property of soluble groups used is closure under normal products and extensions. This should convince you that $G/R$ doesn't have any normal soluble subgroups. Now, if $G$ is any finite group, $T$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$, and $T$ is non-abelian simple, then $G \leq \operatorname{Aut}(T)$. Centralisers of normal subgroups are themselves normal, so $C_G(T)$ is normal in $G$. Since $T$ is non-abelian simple, it follows that either $C_G(T)>1$, whence $C_G(T) \geq T$, or $C_G(T)=1$.  Eliminate the former possibility and use the $N/C$ theorem.

Answer (score 5):

I will make a case distinction on different composition series.

If $G$ has $A_6$ as a composition factor, then the sequence $1 \to C_7 \to G \to A_6\to 1$ or $1 \to A_6 \to G \to C_7 \to 1$ splits by Schur-Zassenhaus. As $A_6$ is simple, there is no non-trivial homomorphism $A_6 \to \operatorname{Aut}(C_7)$, also as $\operatorname{Aut}(A_6)$ has order $1440$, there is no-nontrivial homomorphism $C_7 \to \operatorname{Aut}(A_6)$ so we get $G \cong C_7 \times A_6$, this obviously has an abelian subgroup of order $42$

If $G$ has $\mathbf{PSL}_3(2)$ as a composition factor, then one case is that we have a surjective homomorphism $G \to \mathbf{PSL}_3(2)$, then the kernel has order $15$, and hence is cyclic.

One other case is that we have an exact sequence $1 \to H \to G \to C_3 \to 1$, where $H$ is of order $840$ and has $C_5$ and $\mathbf{PSL}_3(2)$ as composition factors. Schur Zassenhaus gives us that $H$ is a semidirect product of $C_5$ and $\mathbf{PSL}_3(2)=\mathbf{PSL}_2(7)$. $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf{PSL}_3(2))=\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf{PSL}_2(7))=\mathbf{PGL}_2(7)$ has order $336$ and thus no element of order $5$, so we have no non-trivial homomorphism $C_5 \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf{PSL}_2(7))$. As $\mathbf{PSL}_2(7)$ is simple, there is also no nontrivial homomorphism $\mathbf{PSL}_2(7) \to \operatorname{Aut}(C_5)$. So we get that this semidirect product is split in either case, so $H \cong C_5 \times \mathbf{PSL}_2(7)$ and from there obviosuly $H$ and thus $G$ have an abelian subgroup of order $35$.

The remaining case is that we have an exact sequence $1 \to H \to G \to C_5 \to 1$, where $H$ has composition factors $\mathbf{PSL}_2(7)$ and $C_3$.
One case is that we have an exact sequence $1 \to C_3 \to H \to \mathbf{PSL}_2(7) \to 1$. Because $\mathbf{PSL}_2(7)$ is simple, the associated homomorphism $\mathbf{PSL}_2(7) \to \operatorname{Aut}(C_3)$ is trivial, thus $C_3 \subset H$ is central, so we can take an element $x$ of order $7$ in $H$ and consider the subgroup generated by that element and the central $C_3$ to get an abelian subgroup of order $35$ in $H$ and hence in $G$.
The other case is that we have an exact sequence $1 \to \mathbf{PSL}_2(7) \to H \to C_3 \to 1$. In this case, as $\mathbf{PSL}_2(7)$ is normal in $H$, we get $H \leq N_G(\mathbf{PSL}_2(7)$. If we consider the conjugation homomorphism $H \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf{PSL}_2(7))$, the kernel must have an element of order $3$, because $9 \mid |H|$, but $9 \not \mid |\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf{PSL}_2(7))|=|\mathbf{PGL}_2(7)|=336$, thus there is an element of order $3$ which centralizes the copy of $\mathbf{PSL}_2(7)$. Taking the subgroup generated by this element and an element of $\mathbf{PSL}_2(7)$ gives an abelian subgroup of order $21$.

There is also $\mathbf{PSL}_2(8)$ of order $504$. We can use Schur-Zassenhaus again to get a semidirect product of $\mathbf{PSL}_2(8)$ and $C_5$. Since $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf{PSL}_2(8))=\mathbf{P\Gamma L}_2(8)$ has order $1512$, we get a direct product, which finishes this case.

It remains to treat the case that $G$ has $A_5$ as a composition factor:

One possibility is that we have a surjective homomorphism $p:G \to A_5$. Consider a copy of $A_4$ inside of $A_5$, then the preimage $H := p^{-1}(A_4) \leq G$ is a subgroup of order $2520/12=210=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$, so as $H$ has squarefree order, it is solvable, thus by Hall's theorem, there is a Hall $\{5,7\}$-subgroup of $H$ which must be abelian.

Another possibility is that we have an exact sequence $1 \to H \to G \to C_7 \to 1$, where $H$ has order $360$. By Schur-Zassenhaus, this sequence splits, so $G$ is isomorphic to a semidirect product $H \rtimes C_7$. As $360 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$, any action of $C_7$ on a set of $360$ elements must have at least $3$ fix points. Choose $x \in H$, not the identity element that is fixed by the action of $H$, then by the construction of the semidirect product, elements in $C_7$ commute with $H$, so the subgroup in $H \rtimes C_7$ generated by $x$ and $C_7$ is abelian (and it has at least order $14$.)

We also have the possibility that we have an exact sequence $1 \to H \to G \to C_3$, where $H$ has order $840$ and composition factors $A_5$, $C_7$ and $C_2$.
One subpossibility is that we have a surjective homomorphism $p:H \to A_5$, then we can take (again) the preimage $p^{-1}(A_4)$ which will be a subgroup of order $840/12=70$. Every group of order $70$ has a subgroup of order $35$, which must be abelian.
Another subpossibility is that we have an exact sequence $1 \to K \to H \to C_7$, where $K$ has order $120$ and has composite factors $A_5$ and $C_2$.
This sequence splits by Schur-Zassenhaus, so $H \cong K \rtimes C_7$.
It's possible to show that the only groups with these composition factors are $A_5 \times C_2$ and $S_5$, since this argument is already long enough, I'll skip that part. ([See for example here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_120#Classification_of_non-solvable_groups).) If $K= A_5 \times C_2$, then we can take a cyclic subgroup of $A_5$ that generates together with $C_2$ and abelian subgroup of order $12$. If $K=S_5$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(K)=S_5$, which doesn't have elements of order $7$, so the homomorphism $C_7 \to \operatorname{Aut}(K)$ is trivial and we get $H \cong S_5 \times C_7$, which obviously has an abelian subgroup of order at least $12$.
The last subpossibility on this level of case distinctions is that we have an exact sequence $1 \to K \to H \to C_2 \to 1$, such that $K$ has order $420$ and has composition factors $A_5$ and $C_7$.
There are no non-trivial homomorphism $A_5 \to \operatorname{Aut}(C_7)$ or $C_7 \to \operatorname{Aut}(A_5)=S_5$, because $A_5$ is simple and $S_5$ doesn't have an element of order $7$, so yet another Schur-Zassenhaus argument shows that $K \cong A_5 \times C_7$, which has an abelian subgroup of order at least $12$.

There's the case left where we have an exact sequence $1 \to H \to G \to C_2 \to 1$, where $H$ has order $1260$ and has composition factors $A_5$, $C_3$ and $C_7$.

In the first subcase, we have an exact sequence $1 \to K \to H \to C_7 \to 1$, where $K$ has order $180$. Schur-Zassenhaus gives us that $H \cong K \rtimes C_7$. Because $180 \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$, every action of $C_7$ on a set of $180$ elements has at least $5$ fix points, so we may choose a non-identity element in $H$ which is fixed by the action of $C_7$, this element together with $C_7$ generates an abelian subgroup of order at least $14$ in the semidirect product.

Another subcase is that we have a surjective homomorphism $p:H \to A_5$, then taking the preimage $p^{-1}(A_4)$ gives a subgroup of $H$ of order $1260/12=105=3\cdot5\cdot 7$. As $105$ is squarefree, groups of order $105$ are solvable, so they contain a $\{5,7\}$-Hall subgroup by Hall's theorem which must be abelian and of order $35$.

The last subcase is that we have an exact sequence $1 \to K \to H \to C_3 \to 1$ where $K$ has order $420$ and composite factors $A_5$ and $C_7$. We have already shown in another part of the argument that this implies that $K \cong A_5 \times C_7$ which has a large enough abelian subgroup.

Done!
I hope I made no errors in this long argument, but it's only a handful tricks applied multiple times.

Comment: Right, sorry I missed that case. Will update.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a closer look at the $3$-subgroups, you do not have to rely
on the classification of finite simple groups of order dividing $2520$:

Let's assume that $G$ is a group of order $2520$ without any abelian
subgroups of order $\ge 12$.

We'll frequently use the fact that

(*) elements of order $5$ or $7$ cannot
normalize any non-trivial $3$-subgroup,

as they would centralize it yielding an abelian subgroup of order $\ge 12$.

In particular, $G$ has at least two different Sylow $3$-subgroups.

**Claim**: The intersection $S\cap T$ of any two (different) Sylow
$3$-subgroups $S$ and $T$ of $G$ is trivial.

Otherwise $S\cap T$ has order $3$ and its centralizer $C = C_G(S\cap T)$
has at least two different Sylow $3$-subgroups ($S$ and $T$, as they are
abelian). As $C$ cannot have elements of order $5$ or $7$, its order $|C|$
divides $2^3\cdot 3^2$ and $C$ has four Sylow $3$-subgroups. So it has an
abelian subgroup of order $4$ centralizing $S\cap T$ leading to a
contradiction.

**Claim**: The number $n_3$ of Sylow $3$-subgroups of $G$ is $280$.

By (*) the number $n_3$ is a multiple of $35$, so it is either $70$ or
$280$ by Sylow.

In case $n_3 = 70$ take a look at the action by conjugation of a fixed
Sylow $3$-subgroup $S$ on the set of all Sylow $3$-subgroups.
If an element $1\ne s\in S$ fixes a Sylow $3$-subgroup $T$, i.e.,
$T^s = T$ then it is contained in $T$, $s\in T$, as otherwise $s$ and $T$
generate a $3$ subgroup $\langle s, T\rangle$ properly containing the
Sylow $3$-subgroup, which is absurd.
As therefore every non-trivial element of $S$ fixes only $S$, all other
orbits have length $9$ contradicting $63 \ne 1 \bmod 9$.

**Final contradiction**: $n_3$ cannot be $280$ either.

As you already noted, one can obtain a contradiction using the
$N/C$-theorem.

---

An alternative argument (with three different endings) for the final
contradiction can be given using Frobenius groups:

As $n_3 = 280$ implies that the Sylow $3$-subgroups are self-normalizing
(i.e., equal to their normalizers) and intersect trivially by the first
claim, $G$ is a Frobenius group with Frobenius complement any Sylow
$3$-subgroup. By Frobenius $G$ has a normal subgroup $K$ (the Frobenius
kernel) of order $2^3\cdot 5\cdot 7$.

*Ending 1*: By John Thompson's famous thesis $K$ is nilpotent, which implies
that $K$ has an abelian subgroup of order $140$.

*Ending 2*: One can repeat the argument just given by looking at the Sylow
$5$-subgroups of $K$ to show that $K$ is a Frobenius group with Frobenius
complement any Sylow $5$-subgroup and Frobenius kernel $N$ of order
$2^3\cdot 7$. $N$ is normal in $G$ and has either a normal Sylow
$7$-subgroup or is a Frobenius group with Frobenius complement any Sylow
$7$-subgroup and Frobenius kernel the normal Sylow $2$-subgroup.
Both cases easily lead to abelian subgroups of order $\ge 12$.

*Ending 3*: An even easier way to finish the proof is to look at the action
by conjugation of a Sylow $3$-subgroup $S$ of $G$ on the Sylow
$5$-subgroups of $K$ ($G$'s Frobenius complement). As the number of Sylow
$5$-subgroups of $K$ is **not** a multiple of $3$, there is at least one
fixed point $U$, which is normalized and hence centralized by $S$ giving
an abelian subgroup $US$ of order $45$.